# php code works wrong

Tags: php, mysql

Well, something going wrong here. I type username and password which are exist in my DB. It should `echo` this string in such situations

> need to activate

but it echo this

> You need to reg

init.php

```
<?php
    //error_reporting(0);
    session_start();

    require 'dbconnect.php';//this works okay so i wouldn't post this file code
    require 'users.php';

    $errors = array();
?>
```

users.php

```
        <?php

        function user_exists($username){
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM `users` WHERE 'username' = '$username'");

            if (!$query) {
                die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
            }

            return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;

        }

        function user_active($username){

            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

            $querytoo = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM `users` WHERE 'username' = '$username' AND 'active' = 1");

            if (!$querytoo) {
                die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
            }

            return (mysql_result($querytoo , 0) == 1) ? true : false;

        }
    ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include 'init.php';


if(empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){
        $errors[]='You need to enter a username and password';
    } 
    elseif(user_exists($username) === false){
        $errors[]='You need to reg';
    } 
    elseif(user_active($username) === false){
        $errors[]='need to activate';
    } 
    else {
    //
    }

    print_r($errors);
}



?>
```

part of html

```
<form action="login.php" method = "post">
                    <ul id="login">
                        <li>
                            username:<br>
                            <input type="text" name="username" size="30" value=""/></li>
                        <li>password:<br>
                            <input type="password" name="password" size="30" value=""/></li>
                        <li><input type = "submit" value ="Log in"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="register.php"> Register</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

P.S.
text of querys is works fine, i checked it in mysql. in php code when I type `` instead of '' here

> SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM `users` WHERE 'username' = '$username'
>   AND 'active' = 1

appears

> 'Could not query:'

thing

and i tried `elseif` and `else if` things so i don't think that problems is there

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong. You are comparing a static strings to your value, not a column name:

```
    SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM users WHERE 'username' = '$username' AND 'active' = 1
```

should be

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND active = 1
```

Note that I removed the ' from the column names. It is also valid to use backticks:

```
SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM users WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1
```

Comment: It says >Could not query:Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'

Comment: but column user_id is exist i checked it

Comment: could you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`?

Comment: weel, if i understood you right i typed `echo mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE users");` inside function `user_exists` and now it's says Resource id #6 Could not query:Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'

Comment: oh damn guys it was smth with sql i just reebot it and now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

using `'` around table/field names in a query turns them into strings, and they will not longer be treated as field/table names. That's why there's backticks, for escaping such field/table names that happen to be keywords. The ONLY time you HAVE to escape field/table names is if they're reserved words.

Which means that...

```
SELECT COUNT('user_id')
             ^-      ^-
FROM `users`
WHERE 'username' = '$username' AND 'active' = 1");
      ^--      ^--                 ^-     ^-
```

is completely wrong. You're counting a fixed string, you're comparing the provided username against a string whose value is `username`, and ditto for `active`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query to check the existence of a user is probably one of your problem :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM `users` WHERE 'username' = '$username'");
```

In that query, you are using single quotes on your column name. Which results in comparing two strings, and, unless you have a user name called `username`, it will always return `0`. Escape your columns with an ` char.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

or don't use anything

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Comment: same here Could not query:Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'

Comment: I just used what you wrote (`user_id`). However, I'm glad it worked now that you rebooted.

Comment: thanks! 
and now is apache crushes http://gyazo.com/a3e65d30d251d5dd94608893c73d3c59
i think i should reinstall Denwer. again. oh.

Answer (score 1):

Have you remembered to register the username into the session, as well as get it afterwards?

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: Well where are the $username variable coming from?